# How do I run this image proxy under a different path?

Tags: go

I am using https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy to fetch and resize images on behalf of users. The default app works but I'd like to integrate this with an existing server and change the path to "/proxy/" since "/" will be used for my main app. I also don't want to have to run this separately since it's literally just a few lines I need. I have:

```
p := imageproxy.NewProxy(nil, nil)
p.SignatureKey = []byte("secret key")
p.Timeout = 10 * time.Second

router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.NewRoute().Name("proxy").Methods("GET").Path("/proxy/").Handler(p)

server := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "127.0.0.1:8000",
    Handler: router,
}
```

I receive "404 page not found" for every image. Changing it to:

```
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "localhost:8000",
    Handler: p,
}

log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
```

works. Is it possible to do change the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [http.StripPrefix](https://godoc.org/net/http#StripPrefix) to remove "/proxy" from the request path before invoking the image proxy handler:

```
router.NewRoute().Name("proxy").Methods("GET").PathPrefix("/proxy/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/proxy", p))
```

Also, use [PathPrefix](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.PathPrefix) instead of Path for match on all paths below "/proxy".

Comment: still get a 404

Comment: seems to break the resizing.

Comment: Debug by checking the value of r.URL.Path on [this line](https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/blob/e7f9017674d9badb025048fb73bfa39782016e5d/imageproxy.go#L118).  That should tell you if the problem is with the mux or strip prefix or something else.

Comment: Fixed by removing trailing / from first argument to http.StripPrefix.

Comment: @kristen It works for me.  Here's my program: https://play.golang.org/p/93fSQIIrIv.  Here's the URL I used to test it: http://localhost:8000/proxy/250x/https:/octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg

Comment: I'm retarted. Browser cached my image. Full refresh and it works. Please create answer on other question and I'll accept. Thanks!