# Cannot resize image on image proxy

Tags: go

I am trying to integrate [github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/](http://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/) on an existing server and have the images served on "/proxy/" path. I have:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "willnorris.com/go/imageproxy"
)

func main() {
    p := imageproxy.NewProxy(nil, nil)

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.NewRoute().Name("proxy").Methods("GET").PathPrefix("/proxy/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/proxy/", p))

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8000",
        Handler: router,
    }

    //server.Handler = p

    log.Printf("Listening at %v", server.Addr)
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

When I try to resize an image, the first digit seems to get cutoff:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/proxy/250x,/https:/octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg`

returns a 50x50 image rather than a 250x250 image.

A 250x250 image is accessable by
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/proxy/2250x,/https:/octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg`

Uncommenting `server.Handler = p` works and images are resized as expected.

Comment: Debug by checking the value of r.URL.Path on [this line](https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/blob/e7f9017674d9badb025048fb73bfa39782016e5d/imageproxy.go#L118).  If the path is `/250x,/https:/octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg`, then something is amiss in the proxy code.  Otherwise, there might be problem with what http.StripPrefix is doing.

Comment: See updated answer to   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736050/how-do-i-run-this-image-proxy-under-a-different-path/47736401#47736401. The first argument to StripPrefix should not have a trailing "/".

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. To answer your first point above: http://127.0.0.1:8000/proxy/250x,/https:/octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg results in "250x,/https:/octodex.github.com/images/codercat.jpg" so it doesn't seem like it is getting cut off there.

Comment: Yikes, I deleted the wrong /. Answer updated again. Use current answer.  The answer my comment above directly points to the problem.  The original call to http.StripPrefix chopped off one too many characters.

Comment: You can have a look at [nuggan](https://github.com/cchantep/nuggan) (I'm a contributor of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [http.StripPrefix](https://godoc.org/net/http#StripPrefix) to remove "/proxy" from the request path before invoking the image proxy handler. Note that there's not a trailing / on the first argument to StripPrefix.

```
router.NewRoute().Name("proxy").Methods("GET").PathPrefix("/proxy/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/proxy", p))
```